# Not able to use EventFiringWebDriver object in child class

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am try to set up EventFiringWebDriver in my poject, I am stuck up at some point where EventFiringWebDriver object is working fine in the same class & not working in the child class.

Parent class:

```
package utility;

import java.util.List;

import org.openqa.selenium.Alert;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.events.EventFiringWebDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterClass;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;

import eventListeners.WebDriverEventHandler;


public class common {
    public static WebDriver driver = null;
    protected static EventFiringWebDriver eDriver;
    WebDriverEventHandler handler;
    protected NavigatetoOverviews nav;

    @BeforeClass
    public void beforeClass() throws InterruptedException {

        handler = new WebDriverEventHandler();
        System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.profile", "default");
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        eDriver = new EventFiringWebDriver(driver);
        eDriver.register(handler);

        nav = new NavigatetoOverviews();
        eDriver.get("http://google.com");
    }
}
```

My child class:

```
package eventListeners;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import bsh.commands.dir;
import utility.common;

public class TestExtendsCommon extends common{

    @Test
    public void sample() {

        eDriver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        eDriver.findElement(By.id("gbqfq")).sendKeys("Selenium");
        eDriver.findElement(By.id("gbqfba")).click();

    }
}
```

My Test Results:

```
[TestNG] Running:
  C:\Users\Hema\AppData\Local\Temp\testng-eclipse--492139263\testng-customsuite.xml

Just before beforeNavigateTo http://google.com
Inside the afterNavigateTo to http://google.com
FAILED: sample
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at eventListeners.WebDriverEventHandler.beforeFindBy(WebDriverEventHandler.java:35)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.events.EventFiringWebDriver$1.invoke(EventFiringWebDriver.java:78)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy5.beforeFindBy(Unknown Source)
    at       org.openqa.selenium.support.events.EventFiringWebDriver.findElement(EventFiringWebDriver.java:183)
    at eventListeners.TestExtendsCommon.sample(TestExtendsCommon.java:17)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:84)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:714)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:901)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1231)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1224)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1149)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1057)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:111)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:204)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:175)


===============================================
    Default test
    Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================


===============================================
Default suite
Total tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================

[TestNG] Time taken by [FailedReporter passed=0 failed=0 skipped=0]: 7 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.JUnitReportReporter@77afea7d: 23 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.EmailableReporter2@6d86b085: 8 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.jq.Main@299a06ac: 34 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.XMLReporter@4ac68d3e: 9 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.SuiteHTMLReporter@1f89ab83: 40 ms
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: eDriver value might be null, so you may get Null pointer exception. And why you're running the setup in one class and test in another class. i don't recommend that.

Comment: @VigneshParamasivam Thanks for the reply. For each class we write in our project, that driver setup we need. So i am writing in a class & extending that to each class.

Comment: @VigneshParamasivam Yeah, even i think eDriver value is null. i even tried to return the eDriver from class1 & tried to use that in Class2. In this scenario also it is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for everyone who spent some time on the question. Finally i found the answer.

As the error says, bug is in `beforeFindBy` method in `WebDriverEventListener` class.

```
at eventListeners.WebDriverEventHandler.beforeFindBy(WebDriverEventHandler.java:35)


public void beforeFindBy(By arg0, WebElement arg1, WebDriver arg2) {

    System.out.println("Just before finding element " + arg1.toString());
}
```

In the above program, `arg1` parameter will be `null` when you are finding element by WebDriver object. So i have modified the code like below:

```
public void beforeFindBy(By arg0, WebElement arg1, WebDriver arg2) {

        if (arg1 == null) {
            System.out.println("Just before finding element: " + arg0.toString() + " on browser: " + arg2.toString() );

        } else {
            System.out.println("Just before finding element: " + arg0.toString() + " inside " + arg1.toString() + " Web element on browser: " + arg2.toString() );
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem is with the beforeFindBy method only, here I have modified the code...

```
public void beforeFindBy(By arg0, WebElement arg1, WebDriver arg2) {

    System.out.println("Just before finding element " + arg0.toString());
}
```

=> It is working for me we have to print by using object of By not WebElement, then it will give you like "Just before finding element By.xpath: //input[@id='email']"

=> I have tried with the above solution provided by HemaSundar but it did not work for me.